# What happened to MEF type, "AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog"?

Tags: .net, types, mef

Many *simple* MEF examples (listed below) uses `AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog`.

- [Hosting MEF in an application](http://mef.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Hosting%20MEF%20and%20the%20Container&referringTitle=Guide) on CodePlex MEF page
- [Simple Introduction to Extensible Applications with the Managed Extensions Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/09/29/simple-introduction-to-composite-applications-with-the-managed-extensions-framework.aspx) by Brad Adams
- [Managed Extensibility Framework Tutorial - MEF](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/ManagedExtensibilityFrameworkTutorialMEF.aspx) by David Hayden

I have downloaded [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25797) source from [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) but still cannot find that type anywhere.

What happened to `AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog` and what is the alternative way of creating a resolver?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They renamed it (along with the other catalogs) to a shorter identifier in drop 4 (we're up to drop 5 now). It's called AssemblyCatalog now. Similarly, DirectoryPartCatalog got renamed to DirectoryCatalog.